# How to schedule a task 1 week after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a task that sends a reminder to a user 1 week after they've signed up to my heroku app.

I'm imagining it would be something like:

```
task :send_reminders => :environment do
   User.send_reminder
end
```

In my user model

```
def self.send_reminder
  User.each do |user|
    if Time.now == user.created_at + 7.days
      ReminderMailer.delay.remind(user)
    end
  end
end
```

Is it a bad idea (takes up dyno time) to check every record's created_at value to work out if it's been a week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create add the user to a queue (maybe using [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)) and [delaying](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions) the reminder for one week. That way you don't have to recheck every user's `created_at` value.

Something like:

```
UserReminder.delay_until(5.days.from_now).send_reminder(@user.id)
```

Comment: With my code would it be: ReminderMailer.delay_until(7.days.from_now).remind(@user)

Comment: With Sidekiq, you should only pass simple JSON datatypes (numbers, strings, boolean, array, hash). So try `@user.id` and find the user in the Sidekiq worker file.